# is it possible to calculate the angle

Tags: geometry

When we see graph of $ y=x^3$ in first quadrant we see it is strictly increasing (although it is strictly increasing everywhere), what is the tending angle formed with $x$-axis and a point some where at infinity of the curve

This question I thought when I was in class $10$ , during discussion with my friends

Comment: What do you mean by _"tending angle"_? Is it the limit of the angle as $x\to\infty$? Also, I do not understand how do you define _"angle formed with $x$–axis and a point $(\dots)$ of the curve"_. How can __angle__ be __formed__ by a __line__ (e.g. $x$–axis) and a __point__? Isn't angle always formed by two intersecting lines?

Comment: no I just mean to say angle formed by $x-axis$ and a line joining origin and a point on curve $(x,y)$ such that $x->\infty$,$y->\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what follows,
I am going to give
informal descriptions.
To make this rigorous,
we would need to
introduce limits,
which I am purposly avoiding.

As $x$ gets large,
the angle 
(or slope)
of $y = x^3$
gets closer and closer
to a right angle,
but it never reaches it.

To see this,
note that the
slope of $y=x^3$
at $x$
is the derivative,
which is $3x^2$.

The tangent of  the angle $t$
with this slope
is
$\tan(t) = 3x^2$.

To estimate $t$
for large $x$,
we use this result:

$\tan(t)\cdot \tan(\pi/2-t)
= 1$.

To see why this is true,
look at a right triangle
with legs
$a$ and $b$.
Then
$\tan(A) = b/a$
and
$\tan(B) = a/b$,
so
$\tan(A)\tan(B)
=(a/b)(b/a)
= 1
$.
But $B = \pi/2-A$,
so
$\tan(A)\tan(\pi/2-A)
= 1
$.

If
$\tan(t)
=3x^2
$,
then
$\tan(\pi/2-t)
= \frac1{3x^2}
$.

We now use the fact that
$\tan(z)$ is close to $z$
for small $z$.

Since $3x^2$ is large,
$\frac1{3x^2}$
is small.
Therefore,
since
$\tan(\pi/2-t)
= \frac1{3x^2}
$,
$\pi/2-t$
is close to
$\frac1{3x^2}$,
so $t$
is close to
$\pi/2-\frac1{3x^2}
$.

Therefore
the angle gets close to
$\pi/2$,
but never reaches it.

Comment: Great approach! Thanks for the proof

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha$ denote angle formed by $x$−axis and a line joining origin and a point on curve $(x,y)$.
Then

\begin{gather}
\tan\alpha = \lim_{x\to+\infty}\dfrac{y(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to+\infty}\dfrac{x^3}{x} = \lim_{x\to+\infty} x^2 = +\infty
\\
\alpha = \arctan \left(\lim_{x\to+\infty}\dfrac{y(x)}{x}\right) = \arctan \left( +\infty\right) = \dfrac\pi2
\\
\bbox[1ex, border:solid 2pt #e10000]{\alpha = \dfrac\pi2}
\end{gather}

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You have shown that $\alpha=\frac{π}{2}$ but are u sure it is exactly equal to $\boxed{\frac{π}{2}}$

Comment: @atul_shivam I do not understand you question. Of course I am sure that $\alpha$ is equal to $\dfrac\pi2$ because (according to your own words!) I have shown that $\alpha = \dfrac\pi2$. These statements are exactly equivalent, aren't they?

Comment: But @marty cohen  has proved that angle will aproch to π/2 but never be exactly equal

Comment: @ashi In the comment "no I just mean to say angle formed by $x$−axis and a line joining origin and a point on curve $(x,y)$ such that $x−>∞,y−>∞$" you are looking for an angle resulting from $x\to\infty$. This notation means that you are looking for a __limit case__ of $+\infty$. Then the angle is $\dfrac\pi2$. Now, if you are interested in the behavior of angle for an arbitrary large $x$, then indeed $\alpha$ will always be less than $\pi/2$, but will get infinitesimally close as $x$ grows. If this was the question you had at the first place, please adjust your notation or problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to think that the slope of the tangent = $ \tan \varphi ,$ when tending angle $ \varphi \rightarrow \pi/2. $